# Migrate SharePoint 2007 site into Office 365

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-online, office-365

here I am trying to migrate SP 2007 Site into Office 365.

Steps I am Followed.

1. I am saved my site as template .stp (without content)
2. Rename .stp to .cab and extract to et manifest.xml.
3. Updated <ProductVersion> 3 to 4 and saved.
4. Created cab file with the help of camaker.exe and rename .cab to .wsp
5. uploaded into Office 365 solution gallerias.

But not working, Why?

What is the solution?

And also I am tried that save the list as list template(without content) as .stp from SP 2007 site and updated <ProductVersion> saved created cab file and renamed .stp and uploaded in to Office 365 List Template gallerias.

This also not working.

Note :

1. The list which is OOB level without any customization it will working in Office 365.
2. I am trying to migrate OOB custom list from SP 2007 to Office 365.

Is there is any way to migrate SP 2007 Site template(.stp) into Office 365(.wsp)

Comment: Can I ask how you're migrating content between the two platforms?  If you're using a third party utility it may have some useful features that can assist with this.

Comment: Ya we are using DocAve Tool.

Answer (score 1):

The .stp file made by SP2007 is much different from a .wsp file.  You have to recreate the site templete in SP2013 and the only way to do that is:

1. Create a blank site from your template in SP2007
2. Upgrade that site to SP2010 (since there is no direct upgrade path from 2007 to 2013)
3. Upgrade that site to SP2013
4. Save the SP2013 site as a template, and now you have the .wsp you can use in O365.